# Proving this group to be always a subgroup of $Aut_{K} F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

While self studying Abstract Algebra from Thomas Hungerford, I have a question in Theorem 2.15 on page 252 whose image I am adding.

Image:

[image]

> Question: Why in every case G must be subgroup of $Aut_{K} F $? (line 1 of proof)

Is it due to : as K will always be a subfield of F?

But can't Group of Automorohisms G be bigger than $Aut_{K}F$ ?

Kindly tell whether I am right or not?

And if I am wrong kindly tell how to deduct if correctly.

Comment: How could $G$ be bigger than $Aut_KF$?  By assumption, every element of $G$ is an automorphism of $F$ that fixes $K$ so $G$ is a subset of $Aut_KF$.

Comment: @lulu got it thanks!!